# SqlAlchemy / PyMysql connection timeout on SSCursor

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I am using sqlalchemy to connect mysql database. My code looks like

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL(**url), connect_args={'cursorclass': SSCursor})
conn = engine.connect()
```

Since it is necessary to obtain huge amount of data from DB at once, I used SSCursor. I did some investigation and I create a scenario where connection is lost after 60 second. It is simulated by simple code, I add timeout(60). I am getting a traceback like following:

```
Exception during reset or similar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 687, in _finalize_fairy
    fairy._reset(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 829, in _reset
    pool._dialect.do_rollback(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/base.py", line 1598, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 788, in rollback
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, "ROLLBACK")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1067, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
Exception ignored in: <bound method MySQLResult.__del__ of <pymysql.connections.MySQLResult object at 0x7fed3af0d828>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1332, in __del__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1434, in _finish_unbuffered_query
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 983, in _read_packet
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'settimeout'
```

I am not able to figure out, how to ensure that connection will time out after different desired time. I tried to use `connect_timeout` in `connect_args` with no change in behavior.

What should I do to ensure connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should change the MySQL server option, 
increase the value of `net_read_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: @cezar: Included into the post, the phrase "increase the value of `net_read_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet`" is definitely a valuable part of the link. If you find it wrong, you may downvote the answer. See that meta post - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer - about what NAA (Not-an-answer) is and what is not.

Comment: @Tsyvarev The part you quoted is certainly valuable, but still insufficient. What is the default value of `net_read_timeout`? How much should it be increased? The answer should contain this information and not rely on the link.

Comment: @cezar: This is a fine line between low-quality answer and NAA. But this is an answer. If you feel it provides insufficient information (in that I agree with you - "increase the value of `net_read_timeout`" is too vague), you may throw corresponded comment to the answerer, or simply *downvote* the post ... or do the both (with an intention to retract downvote after the fixing the post). Just do not flag it.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I try to avoid downvoting, as I regard it as demotivating. Flagging should rather encourage answer improving. But you're right, this is still an answer.

Comment: @cezar: "Flagging should rather encourage answer improving" - But the only thing which a low-rep user sees after being flagged is the flag's comment, which is quite abstract. In cause of pure link-only answer, that abstract comment is actually helpful ("please, provide at least some info from the link"). But in given case the comment would be more specific about what is missed in the answer.

Comment: @kai I tried to use net_read_timeout within the options parameter in sqlalchemy, but that does not seem to work. How do we use this parameter? I mainly want to kill the read part of the query if it is too slow.

Comment: @CatherineAlv you should set this param in mysql server config file such as `/etc/my.cnf` and restart mysql server. Or just enter mysql console, set this param temporarily

Answer (score 0):

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1071, in __del__
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1177, in _finish_unbuffered_query
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 657, in _read_packet
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 688, in _read_bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'settimeout'
```

I encountered the same problem, when I was dealing with a huge data last night. 
I know what cause the problem, it is must be memory/network issues. therefore my solution is:

1. catch the exception
2. sleep 60 sec
3. retry

```py
                try:
                   do_something()
                except pymysql.OperationalError:
                    log.error("error %s: %d %s" % (row["id"], e.args[0], e.args[1]))
                    max_try = 10
                    try_times = 0
                    while con.open is False:
                        if try_times < max_try:
                            try_times += 1
                            time.sleep(60)
                            con.ping()
                    # retry
                    do_something()
```

If you have money, increase memory will be helpful. If you have time, learn much more about mysql, turning the memory and network again and again.

If you just want to enjoy your life, then do a programmer's way. It's not the best solution, but i finished my work.

Comment: This is a complicated problem, not only the db server, but something in you app server also need be aware.